# Rails: get params from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a string that is a url with params in it:

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=zlX&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=something&cts=1279154269301&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=
```

How can can I form an array of all the params from the string? I'm aware of the `params` array that you can access but I'm talking about just any arbitrary string, not one part of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a rails shortcut, but:

```
url = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=zlX&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=something&cts=1279154269301&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai='

params = CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query)

#=> {"hs"=>["zlX"], "oq"=>[""], "cts"=>["1279154269301"], "aqi"=>[""], "rls"=>["org.mozilla:en-US:official"], "hl"=>["en"], "aq"=>["f"], "gs_rfai"=>[""], "aql"=>[""], "q"=>["something"], "client"=>["firefox-a"]}

params = CGI.parse(url)
```

is almost there gives you:

```
#=> {"hs"=>["zlX"], "oq"=>[""], "cts"=>["1279154269301"], "aqi"=>[""], "rls"=>["org.mozilla:en-US:official"], "aq"=>["f"], "http://www.google.com/search?hl"=>["en"], "gs_rfai"=>[""], "aql"=>[""], "q"=>["something"], "client"=>["firefox-a"]}
```